# Use of onUpgrade in android application

Tags: android, database, import, sqliteopenhelper

This is my first time developing android app. I am trying to write an app which is able to import csv files into android sqlite local database.
This is my current design:

1. When user press the button, the old tables will be deleted by using db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ ......)
2. Create new empty table by using db.execSQL(CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ......)
3. Read the contant of csv file and break it down to sub string.
4. Insert the sub string to csv file by using db.insert(TABLE1, null, contentValues);

I would like to ask whether i should try using onUpgrade function to replace my step 1,2. I have done a little studying on update DATABASE_VERSION. If i update the value of DATABASE_VERSION, onUpgrade will be invoked and same function can be done. Is there any difference between using onUpgrade and my coding?Which one is better?

p.s. Please consider that this button will be press once a day.

Here is my coding:

Main Activity

```
button_import_csv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){


            DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_1);
            String CREATE_TB;

            CREATE_TB = "CREATE TABLE adv_sales_order ("
                    + "order_date text not null, "
                    + "cust_code text not null, "
                    + "customer_ref_no text, "
                    + "line_no integer not null, "
                    + "item_code text not null, "
                    + "tran_code text not null, "
                    + "order_qty real not null, "
                    + "constraint pk_adv_sales_order "
                    + "primary key (order_date, "
                    + "cust_code, "
                    + "item_code, "
                    + "tran_code))";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TB);
            try{

                FileReader file = new FileReader("/sdcard/downloadedfolder/A1/adv_sales_order.csv");
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
                ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                String line = "";
                String tableName ="adv_sales_order";

                db.beginTransaction();
                while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] str = line.split("\t");


                    contentValues.put("order_date", str[0]);
                    contentValues.put("cust_code", str[1]);
                    contentValues.put("customer_ref_no", str[2]);
                    contentValues.put("line_no", str[3]);
                    contentValues.put("item_code", str[4]);
                    contentValues.put("tran_code", str[5]);
                    contentValues.put("order_qty", str[6]);


                    db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);

                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                db.endTransaction();
            }catch (IOException e){

            }

            helper.close();
        }
    });
```

DatabaseHelper

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String CREATE_TB;

    CREATE_TB = "CREATE TABLE adv_sales_order ("
            + "order_date text not null, "
            + "cust_code text not null, "
            + "customer_ref_no text, "
            + "line_no integer not null, "
            + "item_code text not null, "
            + "tran_code text not null, "
            + "order_qty real not null, "
            + "constraint pk_adv_sales_order "
            + "primary key (order_date, "
            + "cust_code, "
            + "item_code, "
            + "tran_code))";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TB);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_1);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insert_adv_sales_order (ContentValues values) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert("adv_sales_order", null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: why are you dropping the table just to add new data? seems a bit overkill

Comment: @panini Hello. The new data are totally different from the old one. Some records in old version should be deleted or changed too. I think dropping the old table and just insert all records will be simpler. Otherwise u may need to compare all records in both versions....

Comment: I would have thought something like "DELETE * FROM adv_sales_order" would be better - dropping and re-creating the table seems off to me.

Comment: onUpgrade is used when the table structure changes (ALTER TABLE, ...), such as adding removing, renaming... one or more columns or changing its type or attributes. In my opinion,  DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE is an overkill, compared to DELETE *